# how to count the size of an array object and unwind it in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to count the size of an array object and I also need to get the averages for each field in the array labeled `raised_amount`. However, MongoDB will not let me count the array size after unwinding it(duh). Mongo will not let me count the array size before unwinding either. This is for a class I am taking. Quite the challenge.

```
db.research.aggregate({$unwind:"$funding_rounds"},
    {"$group": {
       "_id":{"name": "$name"},
       "averageFunding" : {
           "$avg" : "$funding_rounds.raised_amount"
        }
      }
    },
    {$project: { count: { $size:"$funding_rounds" }}},
    { $sort: { averageFunding: -1 } },
    {"$limit":10})
```

Take out `{$project: { count: { $size:"$funding_rounds" }}}` and it works! However, I wouldn't have funding_round count. Try to count the rounds by themselves, and it works.

Example of data:

```
{
  "name": "Facebook",
  "total_money_raised": "$39.8M",
  "funding_round": [
    {
      "example": 123,
      "round_code": "a",
      "raised_amount": "1232"
    },
    {
      "example": 123,
      "round_code": "bat",
      "raised_amount": "1232"
    },
    {
      "example": 123,
      "round_code": "cat",
      "raised_amount": "1232"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas on how to count the array size in this aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) expect an array, and you [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) array to object before counting. That's why MongoDB restrict to count size.

Try Below code:

```
db.getCollection('tests').aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            total_money_raised : 1,
            funding_round :1,
            size: { $size:"$funding_round" }
         }
     },
     { $unwind : "$funding_round"},
     { $group:{
          _id: "$name",
          avgFunding : {"$avg" : "$funding_round.raised_amount"},
          size: {$first : "$size"},
          totalCount : {$sum: 1}
        }
     },
     { $sort: { "avgFunding": -1 } },
     { "$limit":10 }
 ])
```

Output:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "Facebook",
    "avgFunding" : 1232.0,
    "size" : 3,
    "totalCount" : 3.0
}
```

---

### If NAME field is unique:

Another thing that I need to mention here is if your `name` field is unique and you just want to have the size of an array you can then `unwind` and then count total documents while `$group` as below:

```
db.getCollection('tests').aggregate([
     { $unwind : "$funding_round"},
     { $group:{
          _id: "$name",
          "avgFunding" : {"$avg" : "$funding_round.raised_amount"},
          size : {$sum: 1}
        }
     },
     { $sort: { "avgFunding": -1 } },
     { "$limit":10 }
 ])
```

**Output:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "Facebook",
    "avgFunding" : 1232.0,
    "size" : 3.0
}
```

Where size is the total count of documents that are unwound from an array.

Comment: Just so future people know in the future, it was the "if NAME field is unique" option that I used